# Cannot Explore Demo Site after Logging in - Cypress

Tags: cypress

`In the code provided below, I am trying to log into the demo website and clicking on Login. However, the I am not able to explore the webpage or test any element. Is it mandatory to use a beforeEach() block?

Cypress goes to Default Blank page, as the code goes to the second 'it' block.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wwdg.png)

`///

describe("Demo Site Automation - Orange HRM Demo ", function(){

```
    it("Logging in Into the site", function(){
        cy.visit('https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login');
        cy.get('div[class="orangehrm-login-form"] p:nth-child(2)').should('exist');
        cy.get('div[class="orangehrm-login-form"] p:nth-child(2)').should('be.visible');
        cy.get('div[class="orangehrm-login-error"] p:nth-child(1)').should('have.text', 'Username :
```

Admin');
cy.get('div[class="orangehrm-login-form"] p:nth-child(2)').should('have.text', 'Password : admin123');
cy.get('.oxd-text.oxd-text--p.orangehrm-login-forgot-header').should('have.text', 'Forgot your password? ');
cy.get('button[type="submit"]').should('have.text', ' Login ').click();
})

```
    it("Exploring the site", function(){
        const required_array = ['Admin','PIM', 'Recruitment', 'Time', 'My Info', 'Performance', 'Dashboard', 'Directory', 'Maintenance', 'Claim', 'Buzz'];
        required_array.forEach(i => {cy.get('.oxd-main-menu-search').should('be.visible')
        cy.get('.oxd-main-menu-search').type(i)
        //cy.get('.oxd-text oxd-text--span oxd-main-menu-item--name').should('be.visible')
        cy.get('.oxd-main-menu-search').type('{selectall}')
        cy.wait(2000)
        cy.get('.oxd-main-menu-search').type('{backspace}')
        cy.wait(3000)})
        cy.wait(10000)
        cy.get('i[class="oxd-icon bi-stopwatch"]').click()
        cy.get('.oxd-text oxd-text--h6 orangehrm-main-title').should('have.text', 'Punch Out')
        cy.get('.oxd-textarea oxd-textarea--active oxd-textarea--resize-vertical').type('What is Lorem Ipsum?')

    })
```

})

`

I am able to fix this problem by using a beforeEach() Block, where the site is logged in using the username and password, before every 'it' block. Here's the following code -

`beforeEach(() => { cy.visit('https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login'); cy.get('input[placeholder="Username"]').type('Admin'); cy.get('input[placeholder="Password"]').type('admin123'); })` 
Is this the only solution?`

Answer (score 3):

You should review the documentation on **Test Isolation** [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation)

> **Best Practice:** Tests should always be able to be run independently from one another and still pass.

With two tests, where the second depends on the action of the first, the second will fail.

The test runner is reset to `about/blank` page after every test. You can avoid that happening by setting the configuration setting `testIsolation:false`, but it's not best practice.

Using `beforeEach()` is the preferred way to achieve login before each test.